# C# Directory.exist always return false on the local network

Tags: c#, networking, directory, impersonation

I'm trying to check wether a directory exist on not or a local network. After some research on stackoverflow and MSDN, I develop my code by using impersonate method. The problem is it's not working very well, The `Directory.exists()` method always return `False` Here you have my code (it's nearly the same as the one from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w070t6ka.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2)):

```
public sealed class SafeTokenHandle : SafeHandleZeroOrMinusOneIsInvalid
    {
        private SafeTokenHandle()
            : base(true)
        {
        }

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        [ReliabilityContract(Consistency.WillNotCorruptState, Cer.Success)]
        [SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        private static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr handle);

        protected override bool ReleaseHandle()
        {
            return CloseHandle(handle);
        }
    }

 class Environment
    {
        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        public static extern bool LogonUser(String lpszUsername, String lpszDomain, String lpszPassword,
            int dwLogonType, int dwLogonProvider, out SafeTokenHandle phToken);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public extern static bool CloseHandle(IntPtr handle);
        const int LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT = 0;
        const int LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE = 2;

        private void m_SendAlertes()
        {
                SafeTokenHandle safeTokenHandle;
                string v_pathToDir = "\\192.168.1.199\Clients SiteInternet";

                if (!LogonUser("RKalculateur", "SERVEUR2", 
                                "riskedge", LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, out safeTokenHandle))
                {
                    int ret = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                    throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception(ret);
                }
                using (safeTokenHandle)
                {
                    using (WindowsIdentity newId = new WindowsIdentity(safeTokenHandle.DangerousGetHandle()))
                    {
                        using (WindowsImpersonationContext impersonatedUser = newId.Impersonate())
                        {
                            if (Directory.Exists(@v_pathToDir))
                            {
                               // Proceed code here
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
    }
```

Here you have a picture of the rights for this directory :
[image]

Comment: Is this a wpf, win forms, or web app?

Comment: Just a normal terminal program in C#

Comment: @LukeMarlin I already read this post, but I don't understand realy how to do it :s... And I don't know what is a IIS

Comment: I think it's not for my configuration. I mean, it's talking about web server and things like that. In my case, It's a local network : it's another computer on the same network as me

Comment: @Yumino You are right, I was convinced you were in Asp.Net, sorry :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's probably an issue connected to user permissions.

From MSDN:

> If you do not have at a minimum read-only permission to the
>   directory, the Exists method will return false.

If you're using local account and not domain account, using Directory.Exists() method is problematic.

I had similar problem in the past: I had to check if a  net share existed in my network and there was no domain. Your way didn't work for me. In the end, I gave up on Directory.Exists() method and ended up using NET USE command  ( http://www.cezeo.com/tips-and-tricks/net-use-command/ )

```
bool exists = false;
string output = "";
string error = "";

System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            ExecuteShellCommand(process, "NET USE", "\""+ @path + "\" "+
               this.password+ " /USER:"+machinename+"\\"+username + " /PERSISTENT:NO",
               ref output, ref error);
Console.WriteLine("\r\n\t__________________________"+
                "\r\n\tOutput:" + output.Trim().Replace("\r", " ") +
                "\r\n\tError: " + error.Trim().Replace("\r"," "));

            if (output.Length>0 && error.Length==0)
            {
                exists = true;
            }

            process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            ExecuteShellCommand(process, "NET USE", " /DELETE " + @path,
                ref output, ref error);
```

....

```
public void ExecuteShellCommand(System.Diagnostics.Process process, string fileToExecute,
        string command, ref string output, ref string error)
    {
        try
        {
            string CMD = string.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, @"{0}\cmd.exe", new object[] { Environment.SystemDirectory });
            string args = string.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "/C {0}", new object[] { fileToExecute });
            if (command != null && command.Length > 0)
            {
                args += string.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, " {0}", new object[] { command, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture });
            }

            System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(CMD, args);

            startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            startInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

            process.StartInfo = startInfo;

            process.Start();

            // timeout
process.WaitForExit(10 * 1000);
output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
             error = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
        }
        catch (Win32Exception e32)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Win32 Exception caught in process: {0}", e32.ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception e
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception caught in process: {0}", e.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            // close process and do cleanup
            process.Close();
            process.Dispose();
            process = null;
        }
    }
```

I know it's a hack but it worked for me and it's a possibility. (Although you may need to set up a proper net share)